# Is it possible to convert file from Blender 3d to svg?

Tags: html5, blender, html-canvas, svg

I want to build web game in html5 with canvas/svg.

Can I convert/export file from blender to canvas/svg?

Maybe via unity3d?

Comment: I really doubt it. I assume that you want the game to scale nicely and thats why you want SVG? If so render your scene multiple times to different resolutions and send over the size that best fit the window/graphics settings.

Comment: You do realize SVG is a 2D graphics format, right? I suppose you could export 3D curves as 2D vectors, or are you asking about rendering out images as vector graphics? Does Blender have a cartoon renderer?

Comment: -1. It's unclear what is being asked here. What should be exported? A rendered image, or a 3D model ("file" is not specific enough)? Then again, why SVG (which is a 2D vector-graphics format). HTML5, canvas and SVG have basically nothing to do with Unity3D as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Three.js](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-webgl/) and use the [Blender to JSON](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender).

Answer (score 0):

There is this - [Blender to WebGL Javascript exporter](https://code.google.com/p/blender-webgl-exporter/)

Comment: Answering the wrong question perhaps? Exporting mesh data for WebGL doesn't help with Canvas and the project doesn't even mention SVGs.

Comment: Ah, possible. WebGL, though, renders on canvas and this might help him achieve what he wants.